# Ford Courier 2005, Cant engage 4wd high gear

Tags: ford, 4wd

I have 4wd Ford Courier 2005, I cant engage into 4 high gear.

Comment: Jay, this looks like your first posting to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair. Welcome. Can you explain what the conditions are for your issue?  Is this a lever or a push button engagement? Have you taken the vehicle to a mechanic for analysis?  Or are you a fix it yourself type of person?  One recommendation is to purchase a troubleshooting manual (Haynes or Chilton) They will have a section that describes the 4 Wheel drive on your vehicle and how it works.  It may also include troubleshooting tips. This could be any issue from bent control rod to broken transfer case.